# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL. I tried googling and looking at other similar posts on stackoverflow and cannot find the error in the following.

```
 SELECT Principal_Balance_Amt, Term_Nbr 
      FROM [ProofOfConcept].[LendingClub].[ds_Lending_Club_Loan_Portfolio_NPI]
      WHERE ndayspastdue >= 30
      AND WHERE ndayspastdue <=60
```

I would appreciate any advice I can get.

Comment: you can have only one `where`... you've got 2.

Comment: To people trying to close. I don't think this is a "typographical error". The submitter doesn't appear to know how where clauses should work. We can educate him on that

Comment: @JoePhilllips I don't agree. The close reason states that _was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._ and I think that applies here, as the most basic research would have unearthed the cause.

Comment: @jpw Good point. I agree with that

Answer (score 1):

You repeated `WHERE` twice, just use:

```
SELECT Principal_Balance_Amt
     , Term_Nbr
FROM [ProofOfConcept].[LendingClub].[ds_Lending_Club_Loan_Portfolio_NPI]
WHERE ndayspastdue >= 30
  AND ndayspastdue <= 60
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `where` clauses. You should remove the second one like:

```
SELECT Principal_Balance_Amt, Term_Nbr 
FROM [ProofOfConcept].[LendingClub].[ds_Lending_Club_Loan_Portfolio_NPI] 
WHERE ndayspastdue >= 30 AND ndayspastdue <= 60
```

Also you can use `between` operator:

```
SELECT Principal_Balance_Amt, Term_Nbr 
FROM [ProofOfConcept].[LendingClub].[ds_Lending_Club_Loan_Portfolio_NPI] 
WHERE ndayspastdue BETWEEN 30 AND 60
```